# calling a column from a dataframe into a function using pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to call a column into a function. When i tried the below way its working

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select col1 from sample")
def samp(col1):
    if col1 ==21: return 'A'
    else: return 'B'

udfsamp = udf(samp,StringType())
df.withColumn("cate",udfsamp("col1")).show()
```

But when i call the function by defining in a seperate srcsamp.py file and do the below

```
from srcsamp import samp
df = sqlContext.sql("select col1 from sample")
samp(col1)
udfsamp = udf(samp,StringType())
df.withColumn("cate",udfsamp("col1")).show()
```

i get the following error

```
NameError: name 'col1' is not defined
```

Is this the right way of calling a column from a dataframe?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: try running your code after deleting the line having `samp(col1)` from second chunk of code.

Comment: HI,
i tried doing this. now it shows Import Error: No module named srcsamp

Comment: Hope your issue is resolved now after following @Marie 's suggestion. Also consider placing srcsamp.py in the same folder where your spark code is saved if you are simply testing this code using an editor.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can actually load this python package: have you added the parent directory of the py file to `sys.path`.

Since you want to use the functions contained in the py file in a UDF you have to deploy the files on the nodes using `--py-files srcsamp.py` when running your application (whether it is a notebook, a pyspark shell or a spark submit)

As @Prem said `col1` was never initiated in your script so calling `samp(col1)` won't work.

Comment: no problem @pranav :) don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question